# Vikneswaran's R companion to experimental design data set

Tags: r, dataset, experiment-design

How can I get the data sets belonging to [*R companion to Experimental Design*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Vikneswaran-ED_companion.pdf) (Vikneswaran, 2006)?

The website link and e-mail that are referenced in this textbook are no longer active.

Comment: No idea. I'm afraid you will have to look for the original data contained in Berger's *Experimental design with application in managament, engineering and the sciences* yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The datasets from the book are available [here](http://www.thomsonedu.com/statistics/discipline_content/dataLibrary.html) but the file names Vikneswaren uses are different.  Unfortunately the ASCII format seems unreadable, but there are lots of others and there is the foreign package in R.  I made up some csv files but haven't gotten around to renaming them and massaging them to match the companion file.

EDIT:  I just checked and the data files are not the same as Vikneswaren uses.  They are similar but not the same data.  Given that they are the files for the book I'm left wondering where the difference comes from.  I tried the SPSS files with `read.spss` but no dice.  The Excel files read in with `read.xls` from the `gdata` package seemed ok.